# Need help on how to sort an array using its elements

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am new to programming. I have a problem trying to sort the array elements.

Program:

```
for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        System.out.print("Enter product ID: ");
        pro[i].product_ID=sc.next();
         System.out.print("Enter product name: ");
        pro[i].name=sc.next();
        System.out.print("Enter price: ");
        pro[i].price=sc.nextFloat();
        pro[i].discount_price=(float)((pro[i].price)/3);
}
for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<50;j++)
        System.out.print("-");
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Product Details:\n");
        System.out.println("Product ID: "+pro[i].product_ID);
        System.out.println("Product Name: "+pro[i].name);
        System.out.println("MRP Price: Rs "+pro[i].price);
        System.out.println("Our price: Rs "+pro[i].discount_price);

}
```

When I tried to print it, it prints in the same order and not according to names. Why the changes in array not gets reflected back?
Please help....
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the logic to sort the array?

Comment: If you can move to ArrayList then it will be simple to sort the list using Comparator.sort(arraylist obj); otherwise you need to write the logic

Comment: @user2115021 `Arrays.sort(array)` can sort arrays

Answer (score 1):

To sort your products by their names you can use

```
    Arrays.sort(pro, new Comparator<Product>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Product p1, Product p2) {
            return p1.name.compareToIgnoreCase(p2.name);
        }
    });
```

(Change `Product` to whatever class you use to represent your products)